# Can't set my tiny2040 pimoroni to print hello world

Tags: raspberry-pi, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, rp2040

I have flashed the latest micropython into my rp2040, can access it, but when I try the simplest code possible exactly like this:

print("hello world")

it returns a bunch of gibberish and syntax error and so on. wth is going on, help please! I need to get it working so I can start actually using this.

Comment: Are you using Thonny IDE?

Comment: Can you provide more information? How are you connecting to the RP2040?